# Worklight 6.2: Is it possible to decommission the device using any WL API

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight 6.2: Is it possible to decommission the devices using any Worklight API apart from Licence Tracking in Worklight Server?

Comment: Define "decommission".

Comment: By "decommission" I meant, not allowing user/device to access to a particular application. But rather doing it manually from the Device management console, is it possible to disable the access of a particular device for an application using Worklight API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how an API would be of help here.

Anyway, the only available feature that allows you to disable a specific device, is the License Tracking feature you have mentioned in your question.

Feel free to submit feature requests: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help/